# node js mysql query in loop error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, for-loop

I am using express, and its my route function. This function retrieve all stores from store table, and then callbacks another series function, that function loop through the stores and find countries from another table according to particular `StoreId`.

Error is

```
    router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next) {
          var stores = [];
async.series([
    function(callback){
    // running mysql query here, then assigning record to stores
      stores = record;
      callback();          
    },
    function(callback)
    {
      async.forEachOf(stores, function(value, key, callback) {
        var Store = stores[key].StoreId;
        Mysql.query(query + Store)
          .then(myCallback(key))
          .catch(function(err)
          {
            return res.send({'success': false});
          });
      })
      callback();
      function myCallback(index)
      {
        return function(record)
        {
          console.log(index); //okhere
          if(record)
          {
            stores[index]['countries'] = record;
            console.log(stores); // store has countires
          }
        }
      }
    },
    function(callback)
    {
      return res.send({'success': stores}); //return store without countries
    },
]);

        });
```

Comment: Hi @Nitin, what is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the value being stored in a closure. When the callback `function(record) {...}` is called, the value of aa is already 3(it was incremented when async calls didn't return.). So in order to correct this, use another function that wraps this function and call that. For example,

```
Mysql.query(query + Store)
    .then(myCallback(aa))


// Function that returns a function that'll
function myCallback(currentAa) {
    return function(record){
        if(record) {
            console.log(currentAa);
        }
    }
}
```